# How can I building a plugin/extension for Google Chrome that creates a shortcut icon to the website on the desktop of the user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, shortcut-file, chrome-plugins

I want to have a `Install` feature such as in this website:
https://lacasadehamburguer.grandchef.com.br/?fbclid=IwAR14WN_LkR92kT8rocPFk4CqEEyAlXA4hA7Gl3SASc_eEg972RG5QckzgvM

When an user click on the button `Install`, it add the plugin as  "installed" into chrome and create a shortuct icon on the user's desktop.

How is this feature called?

Comment: If you feel that I answered the question, please accepte my answer. If you feel that it did not answer your question, please update your question and add more details.

Answer (score 1):

### Declare the PWA (Progress web application) so Google Chrome detects it and offers visitors to install it.

You must write a `manifest` file for your PWA, it describes your application, the version, the theme color, the app icon, etc...

The manifest file look like follow:

```
{
  "background_color": "orange",
  "description": "Cute and random little cat pictures.",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon/cat-icon.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "name": "Cute cat pictures",
  "short_name": "Cats",
  "start_url": "/pwa-examples/a2hs/index.html"
}
```

### Install with Google Chrome desktop

You can test your PWA by installing it from a browser, this is how you install it on Google Chrome:

1. Visit the Single Page application you want to install as a PWA.
2. In the location tab, there is a `+` icon, click on it and select `Install`
3. Notice the application being install on your system and launch it.

### Uninstall with Google Chrome desktop

- Navigate to `chrome://apps/` and right click the application icon and select `Remove from Chrome`

You can read more about this manifest file here:

- https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#0
- https://www.simicart.com/blog/pwa-add-to-home-screen/